# Ruby class with public method

Tags: ruby, class-design

I have a class with a public method, for example:

```
class CsvParse
  def initialize(csv_file)
    @csv_file = csv_file
  end
  def parse
    ...
  end
end

csv_parse = CsvParse.new('csv_file.csv')
csv_parse.parse
```

But the design of the class can be like this too:

```
class CsvParse
  def initialize(csv_file)
    @csv_file = csv_file
    parse
  end

  private
  def parse
    ...
  end
end

csv_parse = CsvParse.new('csv_file.csv')
```

What is the best practice?

Comment: That depends on your use case.

Comment: Write a test for your class - it usually reveals problems in your design. (even better: write the [test first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development))

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case there is a helper method exposed, that parses file to it’s csv representation (whatever it is.)

Semantically the best call would be:

```
csv_parse = CsvParser.parse 'csv_file.csv'
```

So, I would go with declaring constructor private, preventing these objects from being directly created:

```
class CsvParser
  def initialize ...
  end
  private_class_method :new

  def self.parse *args
    CsvParser.send(:new, *args).send(:parse)
  end
private
  def parse ...
end
```

Comment: Why do you call `#new` with `send` and then call the private method directly?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should not start parsing on initialization - according to the single responsibility principle, a method should do one single thing.

Comment: One of the many counterexamples to this claim is `Time.parse`.

Comment: @sawa, `Time.parse` is not an initializer nor it is an instance method - I was talking from the perspective of `initialize` as an instance method

Comment: @SpeedyWizard It returns an instance of time. It does not make difference whether the OP's `parse` is called from `.new` or `#initialize`.

Comment: @sawa, yes, it does - I'm still talking about direct initialization, not via a class method. And `Time.parse` still follows the single responsibility principle - it initializes a new object after parsing some data

Comment: `initialize` is not intended to be normally directly/explicitly called by a user. It is intended to be called from `new`. So it does not make difference.

Comment: @sawa, how does that relate to what I said previously?

Comment: @SpeedyWizard your answer is helpful. Could you extend and add examples it to make your idea clearer?